# FOSRest OPTIONS request return 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: ember.js, fosrestbundle, preflight

I wrote a REST services with Symfony FOSRestBundle. It work fine with GET request.

Now, I am trying to access with Ember « models" and I get an error message. Indeed, Ember try to access with OPTIONS request (preflight) and It failed with « Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response ».
I tried to access the REST service with Postman and I got this error :
with OPTIONS http://myUrl.local/groups : "405 Method Not Allowed »

but it works fine if I call OPTIONS http://myUrl.local/

I use apache under El Capitan (IMac).
I tried to append these lines to /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-default.conf  :
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

I tried to append these lines in directive  in my VirtualHost.
Same results in both case.

Is the problem in Symfony or FOSrestBundle.

I need help to understand what is happening. How I can resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your Ember application is not hosted on the same domain as your Symfony application – it might be an app on your phone? This makes your requests adhere to the CORS protocol (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).

You have correctly identified the headers you need to set. The reason why it doesn't work is that `/groups` probably routes to an action similar to this:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

class GroupsController
{
    public function getGroupsAction()
    {} // "get_users"            [GET] /users
}
```

As this action requires the method GET, FOSRestBundle blocks requests of any other method and returns the status code 405 you are getting. That's also why an OPTIONS request to `/` worked fine – it's not your server blocking it, it's FOSRestBundle.

Use the [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle) to correctly handle preflights. The bundle

- Handles CORS preflight OPTIONS requests
- Adds CORS headers to your responses

See [issue #587](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/587) for reference.